# Tor inhibits URL bar from working

Tags: tor

I got Tor to work on my Ubuntu, working in that it connects and is running. However, when I try to type something into the URL bar or search engine, the keystrokes don't register. If I have Firefox open as well, it doesn't allow Firefox to work either. I've tried it with only the Tor browser open, but I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with IBus. The only solution I know at the moment is to remove IBus and to restart Lightdm. If you are a command line user you can enter the following commands into a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove ibus
sudo service lightdm restart
```

However you can also open your favorite package manager, search for ibus and remove it. After this is done log out and login again (a reboot will also do). Now you can use your keyboard with the Tor Browser Bundle.